# how to rewrite this code to avoid switches/casting

Tags: java, design-patterns

Simplified example to give you an idea, hope it's be clear.
I've already added inheritance for Service class to avoid switches I'm having now

```
class Config {}

class ConfigA extends Config {}
class ConfigB extends Config {}

// service class - different implementation for configA and ConfigB
// normally it would look like
class ServiceA {
    public String run(ConfigA configA) {}
}
```

thus next then I need sth like

```
class ServiceRunner {
    public String run(Config config) {
        // if or switch doesn't matter now
        if (config  instanceof ConfigA) {
            return serviceA.run((ConfigA)config);
        }
    }
}

// main
Config config =  configFactory.create(...) // returns ConfigA or ConfigB
String result = serviceRunner.run(config);
```

Is there a better way to code it I mean without casting?
The only solution I can see is:

```
interface Service { String run(); }

@RequestScope
class ServiceA implements Service {
    private ConfigA  config;
    public ServiceA(ConfigA configA) {this.configA = configA}

    public String run() {
        ...
    }
}
```

but I'm not convinced it's a good idea to implement service beans as state beans and I'm using CDI (quarkus actually) for DI which it seems doesn't support assisted injection via constructor

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hide the detail about which Config a given Service handles inside the Service itself? By doing so you could have something like the following:

```
interface Service { 
   boolean handlesConfig(Config config)
   String run(Config config); 
}

class ServiceRunner {
   
   private List<Service> services;

   public String run(Config config) {
      for (service : services) {
         if (service.handles(config)) {
            return service.run(config);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a case for Bridge pattern. You have parallel hierarchies of service and config. So if tomorrow there is a ServiceC, there would supposedly be a ConfigC. There might be an abstraction which is common in both service and config. Try to find it and abstract it out. Then service would be using that abstraction. And ConfigA, ConfigB would be impls of that abstraction.

Or perhaps, as the replier above mentioned, service should be programmed to the abstract config instead of impls.

Does the Configs have different types of interfaces that can't be extracted into a common interface? In that case, it is violating the Liskov's substitution principle, which requires that all subclasses should be interchangeable. e.g. the hierarchy of Shape <- Rectangle <- Square is wrong, because square is not a type of rectangle (programmatically, of course) - because Rectangle has 2 dimensions, namely length and breadth, while square has one dimension of length only. Making this hierarchy would break the abstraction. Similarly, it might be your case that the hierarchy of Config may not be a hierarchy at all.